# How to convert this SQL Query on Code Igniter Model

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder, codeigniter-database

Good Day Masters,
Can anyone help me how to convert this SQL Query into Code Igniter format (model).

```
SELECT firstName,  FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, birthDate)/365.25) as age  FROM residents_tbl WHERE  FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, birthDate)/365.25) >= 18
```

I don't know how to write it on WHERE clause.

```
    $query = $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->from('residents_tbl');
    **$query = $this->db->where('isHead', '1');**
    $query = $this->db->order_by('lastName', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('', 15, $this->uri->segment(3));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified version with chaining. I just changed the type of `1` from string to number which might caused the problem.

```
$query = $this->db
         ->where('isHead', 1)
         ->get('residents_tbl')
         ->order_by('lastName', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Thank you for this mate.